# Local Azure Mobile Service shows default items instead of modified items

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating a small UWP project in Visual Studio, with an Azure database and an Azure Mobile Service. I downloaded the starter project from the Azure management portal so I've modified next to nothing from the default project.

In the default WebApiConfig.cs class, I have modified the following piece of code:

```
public class WP_TravelApp_G17Initializer : ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges<WP_TravelApp_G17Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(WP_TravelApp_G17Context context)
    {
        List<TodoItem> todoItems = new List<TodoItem>
        {
            new TodoItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First blablablablablab", Complete = true },
            new TodoItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second azerty", Complete = true }
        };

        foreach (TodoItem todoItem in todoItems)
        {
            context.Set<TodoItem>().Add(todoItem);
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

The default ToDoItems were 'first item' and 'second todoitem' for the record, both false. But when I run the service, locally, and I test things with Postman or something similar I get the default items, first item and second item, rather than my modified gibberish items. When I try to do the API call for my app, I get the same default items, but it doesn't even get filled in. Does anyone know what went wrong or where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own issue, with the help of a teacher. The problem wasn't with the WebApiConfig class, the Seed method wasn't being used for some reason.

The problem was that I called the .ToCollectionAsync() method, but the program wasn't awaiting its response. So I had to add await to the method that called the API call.

Answer (score 0):

When you test your starter project, It's coming with localhost settings at default from Azure.

Did you change your config in `App.xaml.cs` to your actual API endpoint published on Azure?

from:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://localhost:50270/");
```

to:

```
 public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://yourservice.azure-mobile.net/",
            "yourazurecridential"
        );
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Yeah, I'd already changed that. It was something else, I'll post the answer iin a bit.